# Getting indices of different lengths to slice a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Given these arrays,

```
  R = np.array([[ 5.,  3.,  2.,  7.,  3.,  6.,  8.,  9., 10., 55.],
                  [ 5.,  4.,  2.,  7.,  3.,  6.,  8., 10., 10., 55.]])
  F = np.array([[ 0.2 ,  0.4 ,  0.1 ,  0.3 ,  0.25,  0.25,  0.2 ,  0.1 ,  0.1 , 0.1 ],
                  [ 0.3 , -0.4 ,  0.1 ,  0.3 ,  0.25,  0.25,  0.4 , -0.4 ,  0.1 , 0.1 ]])
  K = nparray([[2],
                 [1]])
```

I want to sort each row of `F` and then find the first `K[0]` indices of the first row and  the first `K[1]` indices of the second row of the sorted `F`. Then using these indices, I want to add 1 to the elements of `R`.

Here is my attempt, I was able to get the indices:

```
indices = np.argsort(F)[np.tile(np.arange(F.shape[1]),(F.shape[0],1)) < K]
# indices =  np.array([7, 8, 7], dtype=int64)
```

But I am not sure how to vectorize the below operations without using a for loop.

```
Rnew = R.copy()

Rnew[0,7] =R[0,7]+1

Rnew[0,8] =R[0,8]+1

Rnew[1,7] =R[1,7]+1

Rnew = np.array([[ 5.,  3.,  2.,  7.,  3.,  6.,  8., 10., 11., 55.],
                 [ 5.,  4.,  2.,  7.,  3.,  6.,  8., 11., 10., 55.]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
m = np.arange(F.shape[1]) < K
Rnew = R.copy()
Rnew[np.nonzero(m)[0], np.argsort(F)[m]] += 1
```

Since the first line uses broadcasting, `np.tile()` is not needed.

Notice that there is a possible ambiguity of the results: since each row of `F` has values that are repeated several times (e.g. 0.1 in the first row and -0.4 in the second) `np.argsort()` may give different orderings of elements of `F`, depending on how these equal values get sorted. This may change which entries of the matrix `R` will get incremented. For example, instead of incrementing `R[0, 7]`, `R[0, 8]`, and `R[1, 7]`, the code may increment the entries `R[0, 2]`, `R[0, 9]` and `R[1, 1]`. To get unambiguous results you can specify that `np.argsort()` must use a stable sorting algorithm, which will preserve the relative order of elements with equal values:

```
m = np.arange(F.shape[1]) < K
Rnew = R.copy()
Rnew[np.nonzero(m)[0], np.argsort(F, kind="stable")[m]] += 1
```

In this particular example this will increment the entries `R[0, 2]`, `R[0, 7]` and `R[1, 1]`. You need to decide if this is the result that meets your needs.